# Tree Grid with Portfolio Items

Tags: rally, appsdk2

Is it possible to build a rallytreegrid xtype using portfolio item models through the TreeStoreBuilder?  I am able to build a rallyportfolio tree with portfolio items, however have had trouble building a tree grid with this type of object.

Comment: Could you post some example code of what you have tried or any specific errors you are receiving?  The TreeGrid in 2.0rc3 was still experimental so I'm not sure if it supports PI's currently or not.  The grid in the next SDK release definitely will, but maybe we can work around any current issues in this version

Comment: @KyleMorse - The following code does not render a Tree Grid or produce any error.  The same code, with 'User Story' instead of 'portfolioitem/area' does work correctly:  
  
```launch: function() {
 Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
  models: ['portfolioitem/area'],
  autoLoad: true,
  enableHierarchy: true
 }).then({
  success: this._onStoreBuilt,
  scope: this
 });
},
_onStoreBuilt: function(store) {
 this.add({
  xtype: 'rallytreegrid',
  context: this.getContext(),
  store: store,
  columnCfgs: [
   'Name',
   'Owner',
   'Description'
  ]
 });
}```

Answer (score 1):

The following code does not render a Tree Grid or produce any error. The same code, with 'User Story' instead of 'portfolioitem/area' does work correctly:

```
launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
        models: ['portfolioitem/area'],
        autoLoad: true,
        enableHierarchy: true
    }).then({
        success: this._onStoreBuilt,
        scope: this
    });
},
_onStoreBuilt: function(store) {
    this.add({
        xtype: 'rallytreegrid',
        context: this.getContext(),
        store: store,
        columnCfgs: [
            'Name',
            'Owner',
            'Description'
        ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of debugging I was able to get it to work by making a couple small tweaks to your code in the launch function:

```
launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
        models: ['portfolioitem/feature', 'userstory'],
        parentTypes: ['portfolioitem/feature'],
        autoLoad: true,
        fetch: ['Name', 'Owner', 'Description'],
        enableHierarchy: true
    }).then({
        success: this._onStoreBuilt,
        scope: this
    });
}
```

Again, this should work quite a bit smoother in the next sdk release but hopefully this should get you by for now.

Comment: using your code, only user stories and their children are showing in the tree.  Were you able to view features?

Comment: the ideal tree grid would be the one available on the 'Portfolio Items' beta dashboard.  Is this type of grid available through the SDK at this point?

Comment: it will be very soon.  we're planning to release a 2.0 ga version of the sdk early next year which will include the latest and greatest tree grid.